# How to call fucntion when modal close JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, modal-dialog

I need to call a function when modal close. My code as follows,

```
function openModal(divName) {
        $("#"+divName+"Modal").modal({
        overlayClose: false,
        closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>X</a>",
        onShow: function (dialog) {
            $('#simplemodal-container').css({ 'width': 'auto', 'height': 'auto', 'padding-bottom': '1000px' });
            var tmpW = $('#simplemodal-container').width() / 2
            var tmpH = $('#simplemodal-container').height() / 2
            $('#simplemodal-container').css({ 'margin-left': tmpW * -1, 'margin-top': tmpH * -1 });
            },
        close:onClose,
        onClose: ModalClose(),
        opacity: 50,
        persist: true
    });
}
```

I tried two ways to call a function as follows, but both not working

1st way

```
function onClose() {
   alert('called');
}
```

2nd way

```
$('.resetbutton').click(function () {
   alert('called');
}
```

Comment: what modal plugin are you using?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm using Kendo

Comment: change  closeHTML: "<a onclick="onClose();"  href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>X</a>",

Comment: `onClose: ModalClose(),` should be: `onClose: ModalClose,`

Answer (score 0):

From the bootstrap documentations, you can just call the javascript event on closing the modal [Javascript.Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/)

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do the closing function...
});
```

And for Kendo Library you can do the close but without the "()" and this will pass the event "e" in the function

> close: onClose,

[Events in Kendo UI](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/events)

```
dialog.kendoDialog({
    width: "400px",
    title: "Software Update",
    closable: true,
    modal: false,
    content: "<p>A new version of <strong>Kendo UI</strong> is available. Would you like to download and install it now?<p>",
    actions: [
        { text: 'Close', action: onCancel },
        { text: 'OK', primary: true, action: onOK }
    ],
    initOpen: onInitOpen,
    open: onOpen,
    close: onClose,
    show: onShow,
    hide: onHide
});

function onClose(e) {
    show.fadeIn();
    kendoConsole.log("event :: close");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Call another function which you want inside ModalClose(), if it user-defined function